# Aurelia Observe properties in a dynamic array of objects

Tags: aurelia

I have an array that has some objects inside of it.

```
this.mediaService.media.files = [
  { id: 1, progress: 15 },
  { id: 2, progress: 0 }
]
```

As a file is uploaded the progress changes in this external js singleton class that contains `.files`. I need to subscribe to this array and to the property of progress for each file in the array. This array is dynamic so as files are added I need to be able to know this and subscribe to them.

Here is what I have in aurelia:

```
  bind() {
    this.observerLocator
      .getArrayObserver(this.mediaApi.media.files)
      .subscribe(this.addSplicesObservations);
  }

  addSplicesObservations(splices) {
    for (let i = 0; i < splices.length; i++) {
      this.subscriptions.push(this.observerLocator
        .getObserver(this.mediaApi.media.files[splices[i].index], 'progress')
        .subscribe(this.onChange)
      );
    }
  }
```

I noticed though that I don't have access to `this` inside of `addSplicesObservations()`. What is the proper way to do this in aurelia?

Comment: It also might be helpful for you to look at the event aggregator. It's basically a messaging system for aurelia. Really cool stuff that you could probably wire up in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned if you do it this way the `this` will be preserved.

```
bind() {
    this.observerLocator
      .getArrayObserver(this.mediaApi.media.files)
      .subscribe((splices) => {
        this.addSplicesObservations(splices); });
}
```

Notice the subscribe setup is a little different. Now why does that make it different I am not sure.

Comment: To clarify why it makes a difference...you're using a lamba expression which in turn is basically a short way of writing a function and, in your case, passing in splices. So you're able to access "this" within the function and it knows that it's correlated to splices.